# Whats the next desktop application you would like to see moved to the web?

Tags: web-application

I'm trying to come up with some ideas on creating a new web app.
I want it to be a useful web app for business.

Anyone have any itches that need to be scratched?

Comment: community wiki.

Comment: I don't think this is a community wiki–appropriate question. It will probably have **one** answer, being whichever donnyv chooses to create. Individual ideas also won't really need to be edited.

Comment: This is a discussion and it's subjective... there is no real answer to "what would YOU like"... its an opinion.

Comment: Wiki it,                            please.

Comment: It doesn't seem like a discussion, as the OP is asking for opinions on something for him to make. "What would *you* like" is the way people will respond, but the "answer" should be whichever wins out for the OP.

Comment: It's still subjective...

Comment: i am also seeing it must be a wiki :)

Comment: -1, I'm a bit tired of these questions in the site. 'What's your favorite x?' 'what would you like for x?'...

Answer (score 2):

Music players and photo viewers.

I want to upload my media files once (or purchase the rights for digital media), and have all my devices able to play them anywhere.

Comment: This exists already, though not for free.

Comment: True, But i am not familiar with any implementation that looks good.

Comment: @Michael Haren 
Where?

Comment: Try some of these...
http://mp3tunes.com/

Comment: Sorry have to post each url as a comment since it doesn't recognize carriage returns.

Comment: http://www.musicplayer.fm/

Comment: http://classic.diino.com/music-online.html

Comment: http://www.steekr.com/

Answer (score 1):

Something that can compete with Microsoft Excel. There's [EditGrid](http://www.editgrid.com/), but it's slow, unintuitive at times, and lacks a lot of features.

I also had another idea about a year ago. What about a service that lets you upload all of your music onto a server, and then have a Flash-based on-the-web media player to play the music from any computer, at any time? I'm not talking about something like [Grooveshark](http://listen.grooveshark.com/), I'm talking a full-blown media player, like Windows Media Player or iTunes, for the web. I never started this project because the initial costs would be too high, but that may or may not be a problem for you.

Comment: What about Google Docs?

Comment: Google Spreadsheets is a joke. There is no way it can compete with Microsoft Excel for anything except *very* simple spreadsheets that *need* to be hosted online.

Comment: If Google Spreadsheets is a joke then I have no chance. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm still waiting for a good Web-based Editor for development. Mozilla has Bespin<sup>1</sup>, but it's not exactly ready to be used, judging from my experience with it in the past.

<sup>1. https://bespin.mozilla.com/ and http://labs.mozilla.com/projects/bespin/</sup>

Comment: You might want to look at http://ecoder.gmeditor.com

Answer (score 0):

An IM client that encompasses all the different ones out there: Yahoo, AOL IM, MSN, IRC, etc.  Like Trillian or Pidgin, but for the web.

That way I don't have to install the client on every computer I own/access.

-JFV

Comment: http://www.meebo.com/

Comment: @musicfreak:  Never knew it existed.  Thanks!